# Tag for Bulk Rename Utility?

Tags: discussion

I lack sufficient reputation; can someone please create a tag for Bulk Rename Utility?  See [How can Bulk Rename Utility automatically move down to the next file, after the current highlighted file has been renamed?](https://superuser.com/q/1063859/269574).

Comment: Every piece of software doesn't need its own tag, and it can be counter-productive.  Tags help to attract answerers who follow a subject.  If a tag has only one question (or a few), the tag isn't serving any purpose.  If that tag is used in place of a more general one, it will hide the question from people who follow the more general one.  If the question is somewhat generic, a program-specific tag may discourage people from reading the question or answering.  Use program-specific tags when the program has its own following.

Comment: Your question was answered in the comments, adding a non essential tag will not help get you more answers.

Answer (score 5):

A [search](https://superuser.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22Bulk+Rename+Utility%22) turns up only seven questions that mention the Bulk Rename Utility, and out of those, only two or three are actually *about* the tool. The BRU doesn't seem widespread or nuanced enough to merit a tag considering the previous.

Therefore, I don't think we need a tag for it yet. Tag such questions with the OS and what you're trying to accomplish. Mention the specific software and its version in the question too, of course.